Firebase ab test include just logged in users according to the user property
The case for just logged-in/signed up/installed users in the mobile app(iOS/android). After finishing the login user retrieves the membership type and immediately sends it to Firebase analytics as user property.
I want to launch an ab test, that targets membershiptype = {membershiptype1}. If there any options to include a new user with {membershiptype1} to ab test immediately after login, not waiting for 1-2 hours(while analytics data is sent and processed by Firebase)?
It would be wonderful if I have force-push analytics events on the first login and request for remote config immediately after processing, but as I understand, Firebase SDK doesn't have this functionality. Do we have any option to get the correct remote config in this case?

Yes there is an option in Firebase Console UI. You should use Activation event in AB test settings. It works as a trigger -> if user fires the event, then variant from AB test is assigned to the user. If user doesn't fires the event (in your case - user is not being logged in into your mobile app), then variant from AB test is not assigned to the user.
